# Draw a circle tangent internally to a point of an ellipse and to both its axis

Tags: geometry

I would like to know how could I draw a circle that touches an allipse internally and at the same time both of its axis. There are, thus, four possible circles of this kind, all of them congruent, their centers being the vertexes of a square.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to  simply use a CAD system. Any decent one will have a function for constructing a circle tangent to three given curves.

If you want to do the computations yourself, here's how (in outline) ...

Let's use the standard  ellipse with equation
$$
    \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}=1
$$
and let the circle be
$$
(x-c)^2 + (y-c)^2 = c^2
$$
This circle is automatically tangent to the coordinate axes, so we just have to choose $c$ suitably to make it tangent to the ellipse, also.

If you eliminate $y$ from the two equations above, you will get a quadratic equation for $x$ that is satisfied at the intersection points. To get tangency, this equation must have two equal roots, so it's discriminant must be zero. This gives you an equation that you can solve to get $c$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I meant to DRAW the circle by means of compass, straight lines and even conics.

Comment: OK. Since the process I outlined involves solution of a quartic equation (at worst), there may be some theoretical proof that a ruler-and-compass construction is possible. But I have no idea how to do it in practice. I don't even know where my compass is.